# Flex - Insert persistent images to a video

Tags: apache-flex, video, actionscript, graphical-logo

Is there a way to convert frames to a video in flex? If I have a video, I want to brand it by adding adding a persistent logo over it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm resolving this using ffmpeg on server side :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can put any transparent Sprite on top of the video with no effort. Even if your video is Stage Video, it will work because stage video is under flash sprites. (I hope you didn't mean something like encoding logo in video, because this would be hopelessly tougher.)